# C# How to have it read words and output results

Tags: c#, if-statement

Sorry, I am EXTREMELY NEW to C#. I do not have much experience with code, so keep that in mind. I want to have my console application do something like this example:

Who is the best?

(Text be written here^)

IF the answer is tim, then write "Your right!"

If the answer is NOT tim, then write "Wrong!" and the code doews not advance until the word "tim" is put in

Comment: This question is fairly basic and you should be able to find out by yourself if you spend some time learning the language. There's plenty of resources (tutorials, books, etc.) available online. Please avoid using SO as an "online classroom" and do more research before asking.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I totally agree with the other answers and comments, but for convenience here is the code

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Who is the best?");

        var answer = Console.ReadLine();

        if (answer.Equals("tim")){
            Console.WriteLine("You're right!")
        } else {
            Console.WriteLine("Wrong!")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm going to down-vote this just because I think this is encouraging the new behavior of asking other people for pre-built solutions instead of taking the time to research and learn yourself. Reed's answer was better, because it gave pointers in the right direction without giving a copy/paste solution. Poster even put "if-statement" as a tag in the question. Would've only taken a couple searches on that and console methods to come up with an answer on their own.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Console.WriteLine` to write out text, and `Console.ReadLine()` to read in the response from the user.  A `while` loop can be used to keep looping until the reponse matches.